# On-hold questions and answers already submitted

Tags: discussion

Haven't found answer to this question, but I'm probably not looking in the right place.

Scenario:

- Question is asked
- 2 Answers are posted
- Question is marked: "on-hold"

Can the OP accept one of the already-submitted answers?

Comment: Check out the [Closed Question FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10582/182513).  The first paragraph of the answer explains it.  (And as far as the rules of the site are concerned, closed = onhold.

Comment: Thanks - hadn't seen that before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they can.

The question being closed doesn't bear on whether a OP considers an answer to have been helpful.